# Textbox in listview - update source and move focus on tab not working at same time

Tags: wpf, textbox, tabbing, updatesourcetrigger, lostfocus

I have a listview. I have set following int that :-

```
<ListView KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" SelectionMode="Extended">
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style>
     <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
  </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

One column in listview contains TextBox's.

If I set the UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus
in my textbox, I can not tab through the listview...Instead if I set UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, the tabbing is working...but source will not get updated.

Please help me

**EDIT**

```
public class TextBoxBehavior
    {
        #region Attached Property EscapeClearsText


        public static readonly DependencyProperty EscapeClearsTextProperty
           = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EscapeClearsText", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnEscapeClearsTextChanged)));


        private static void OnEscapeClearsTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                var textBox = d as TextBox;
                if (textBox != null)
                {
                    textBox.KeyUp -= TextBoxKeyUp;
                    textBox.KeyUp += TextBoxKeyUp;
                }
            }
        }


        private static void TextBoxKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                //((DataContext<string>)((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).DataItem).RollbackChanges();
                ((TextBox)sender).Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {                
                ((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
                                }
        }

        public static void SetEscapeClearsText(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool escapeClearsText)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(null, dependencyObject))
                dependencyObject.SetValue(EscapeClearsTextProperty, escapeClearsText);
        }


        public static bool GetEscapeClearsText(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(null, dependencyObject))
                return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(EscapeClearsTextProperty);
            return false;
        }


        #endregion Attached Property EscapeClearsText
    }
```

Below is the listview/gridview column which has the attached property in it.

```
 <GridViewColumn  Width="60">
                                            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Priority"
                                              Command="{Binding Path=SortSelectedClaimCodeGroupsCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="Item.IntPriority">
                                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Border DataContext="{Binding Item.Priority}"
                                                        Style="{StaticResource ValidationResultBorderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                                        <TextBox Width="200" MaxLength="25" Text="{Binding Path=Value,Mode=TwoWay,                         
                                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" local:TextBoxBehavior.EscapeClearsText="True" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the UpdateSourceTrigger as explicit, you have to update the source by explicitly calling the method UpdateSource on your BindingExpression. Where is the code for that?

**EDIT**

In your TextBoxKeyUp event you are overwriting your Binding by setting the text on the press of Escape key. Firstly you bind it to the property Value and later you are explicitly setting the Textbox text property to String.Empty.This way text property will loose it's binding. So, later whenever you call UpdateSource it won't propagate to Source value since it's no longer binded to the Text property of textbox. Instead you should set the text like this -

```
((TextBox)sender).SetCurrentValue(TextBox.TextProperty, String.Empty);
```

This way your binding will be preserved and UpdateSource would work as it should.

Comment: I am doing that using an attached property  which will take "Enter key" as input.

Comment: First of all UpdateSourceTrigger should not affect your UI tabbing. And secondly when you want your source to be updated? In case press of enter key, have u checked that your code for attached property get called by putting breakpoint there? It will be helpful if you can paste your that code here..

Comment: I have added the code. And I checked if the control comes by putting the break point in it.

Comment: That helps...thanks for your help.But my focus tab-focus issue is still there.

Comment: But you said when you set UpdateSourceTrigger as explicit, your tab issue get solved. What's issue you are facing now?

Comment: I have a lisview with one column(named priority) as editable textbox. 1.) If user change one priority and hit enter key, rearrange the priorities. 
 2.) If user click “tab” to loose focus, 
                a-> if  user changed one priority rearrange the priorities (as in case of Enter key)..and move to next priority textbox (or next focusable control)
b-> If user didn’t change any priority,    just move to next priority textbox (or next focusable control)